# How to initialize variable dynamically in class declaration, and being not constant

Tags: c++, oop, c++17

How to initialize variable(s) dynamically i.e. being not as constant, in class declaration which will be invoked/used without need of object instantiation such as a constructor for member function call immediately gets returned in a function ?
There must, side by side of that variable(s) in that class, be a constant member.

```
enum Value :int { NO,LOW,MED,HIGH };

template<Value V> class valuation {

public:
    valuation(const ints) : pos(s) {};
    valuation(int a, int b, int c) : j(a), k(b), l(c) {};
    value() {
        if (!V)
        return (j+k+l) * pos;
    }

private:    
    const int pos;
    int j,k,l;
};


int a_function(int s) {
    return valuation<NO>(s).value();  // no need object at all
}


int main() {
    // somehow in run-time j, k, l has been given 1,2,3, or other valid values
    int v = a_function(7)   // e.g.
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear why you want to avoid an object or constructor.

Comment: What values should `a_function` and `value` return in your scenario? You have plenty of UB here, firstly you don't initialize all of the `valuation` members in any of constructors. Also you miss `else` case in `value` function, what should happen for `V != 0`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to declare your `value` method -- or at least a version of it -- as a [static member](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm). This will allow you to call the method without instantiating an object from your class.